# different catalog_product_view per category

Tags: magento2, layout, configurable-product

So I have a webshop that needs different ways of showing product detail pages.
For example:
**product A** is a configurable product that needs to show a contact form.

But **product B** is also a configurable product that doesn't need to show that form but a picture.

Also, the simple products that come from **product A** would need to have the same layout as **product A**.

I originally tried to do this by creating custom product types, but i can't figure out how to make my custom product types configurable in the right way. I would still like to do it this way if someone has an idea how to do it.

So now I'm looking for a different way. 
For product types you can use:  `catalog_product_view_type_custom.xml`
Is there a way to do this per category the product is in? Or maybe per attribute?